# CakePHP Pagination gives an "Limit 20 Offset 0" error

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, cakephp, pagination

I am trying to get all the users and I'm using pagination for that.

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->paginate = [
            'contain' => ['Groups']
        ];
        $users = $this->paginate($this->Users);

        $this->set(compact('users'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
    }
```

However after `$this->paginate` I am getting a

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'groups Groups ON Groups.id = (Users.group_id) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0' at line 1
```

Can't find what is the issue why this causing.

Does anyone know why I am getting this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You must rename your table **Groups**. Since v8 this is reserved word. You can view here for more details about reserved words: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Another solution may be to wrap the reserved word in **`** (Grave accent)

Comment: The wrapping happens if you use the identifierQuoting option as enabled in config of CakePHP :)  See [tips](https://sandbox.dereuromark.de/pages/beginner-tips#enable-quote-identifiers)

Comment: This is what **Syntax error or access violation: 1064** indicates. There is no error in the LIMIT OFFSET syntax

Comment: Yes, exactly :) I pointed to the solution of how to enable identifier quoting to not have issues with reserved keywords.

Comment: Oh, ... sorry, my bad then, you are totally correct, nice one